# PHP AltoRouter Call a method on Controller

Tags: php, altorouter

Trying to call a method on a controller but this wont work on AltoRouter

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/users/[i:id]/', 'UserController#showDetails' );
```

What I'm doing wrong?

PS:There is no example on how to get the parameters on the Controller method either.

Answer (score 1):

The route is correct - assuming the `UserController` is in the global namespace. If not, make sure to use the fully qualified namespace in the string.

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/users/[i:id]/', 'App\UserController#showDetails' );
```

Then, in your controller, you will access the parameter like this:

```
public function showDetails ($id) {

}
```

The `[i:id]` means to match an `integer` as a variable named `id`.

Comment: I'm really lost, I can use Laravel routes and everything but with AltoRouter I can only make to work a callable function ie: `$router->map( 'GET', '/hello', function() {....`...can you please post the full scripts

Comment: Should I use `call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); ` or `require $match['target'];` ??

Comment: Can you please post all the files......index.php....UserContorller.php and their specific path

Comment: why are you not using laravel routes in a laravel project?

Comment: At the top of your `UserController` script, you should have a namespace. Something like `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`  If that is the case, then you will access it like this:  `App\Http\Controllers\UserController#showDetails` -- If not, then you will access it like this: `\UserController#showDetails`.

Comment: Is not a laravel project...I just mentioned laravel in the sense that I've used  Laravel before in other projects.

Comment: Ok I added the namespace on the controller file but still no success. On the routes index.php file If I put it that way  `App\Http\Controllers\UserController#showDetails` I get `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required...` If I change it to `App\Http\Controllers\UserController.php` theres no error but nothing happens

Comment: If it's not a laravel project I doubt if that's your actual name space

Comment: I just created that directory structure from your example, I didn't had any of that before.

Comment: I got it, the whole thin was simply replacing `UserController#showDetails` by `UserController::showDetails`...that is the only way `call_user_func()` can call another method inside the class.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't have any problems with using #, but I'm glad it's working for you.

Comment: Ummm interesting...might be the Autoloader? Im using `SplClassLoader.php`... I didn't installed AltoRouter from composer...I just got the source files and added an Class loader